# Dockerfile not enabling autoptimize

Tags: docker

Im pulling a wordpress image and everything is working fine but when I go to the wordpress editor page the following error is on the top of screen.

Autoptimize cannot write to the cache directory (/var/www/html/wp-content/cache/autoptimize/), please fix to enable CSS/ JS optimization!

I assumed RUN chown -R www-data:www-data wp-content/ would solve that issue but its not working. Any ideas would be appreciated. My Dockerfile is below.

```
FROM wordpress:4.9.2-php7.2-apache
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data wp-content/

COPY ./src /var/www/html/

# Install the new entry-point script
COPY secrets-entrypoint.sh /secrets-entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /secrets-entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/secrets-entrypoint.sh"]
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["apache2-foreground"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the exact permission but you don't want to be writing inside a container so you should define a volume. Since you don't need the data to persist, you can do this in your dockerfile like:

```
VOLUME /var/www/html/wp-content/cache
```

This will set up a default volume where Docker will choose the location on your host, but you can mount it to a named volume instead when the container is created if you like.

You could also use a [tmpfs](https://docs.docker.com/storage/tmpfs/) volume which is good for things like cache files.